# Como posso ler os custom attributes sem usar reflexão?

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
[Campo(Chave=true)]
public System.Guid EscalaId { get; set; }
```

Sei que posso ler esses tributos usando a classe `MemberInfo`, como diz exemplo na documentação:

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(MyClass);
object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Mas há alternativas sem o uso de reflexão?

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Essencialmente não tem como. Até existem formas absurdas.

Comment: Fazer reflexão sem reflexão. Pra mim isso soa meio estranho.

Comment: É uma parte de um sistema, que se baseia nos atributos das classes para montar comandos SQL. Li que reflexão pode se mostrar lenta em comparação a outras ferramentas, e como essa funcionalidade de montagem de queries é bastante usada, resolvi pesquisar para ver se havia alguma alternativa, como achei apenas exemplos com reflexão, resolvi fazer uma ultima tentatica aqui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como posso ler os custom attributes sem usar reflexão?

Não tem como.

[Como o problema é a questão de velocidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202708/como-posso-ler-os-custom-attributes-sem-usar-reflex%c3%a3o#comment415400_202708), o preblema de velocidade em *Reflection* é na leitura e definição de **valores de propriedades**, não na leitura de atributos de decoração.

Além disso, existem bibliotecas para resolver isso. A mais famosa delas é a [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/), que faz parte do [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/), que faz justamente isso: lê várias coisas por *Reflection*, mas a definição de valores usa código estático gerado dinamicamente em tempo de execução, por [`Reflection.Emit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Desculpa a rapida mudança de assunto, mas o Dapper é usado no proprio StackOverflow, certo? Me lembro de ter lido isso

Comment: Sim, é o micro-ORM de consulta e persistência a banco de dados aqui do site.